# Dummy ImageView not showing image

Tags: android, imageview

It is showing the image in the Android Studio preview but doesn't show anything when I'm running this on my device. Any ideas why this happens? What's wrong with my code?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/myimage" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your project ?

Comment: Tried now, didn't work. the image still won't show.

Comment: Silly question, but to be sure, you are actually using the layout, right?, with `setContentView`, in the java `Activity` I mean.

Comment: yes, pls check your code in the `Activity`, did you `setContentView` by using the right layout.

Comment: Yes. I tried to add a TextView under this ImageView. The TextView shows but the ImageView is invisible.

Comment: Maybe try changing the image, maybe something makes it incompatible with your device? I'm just saying things, I don't see anything wrong in that section of the code, you could post more code, maybe something is wrong there, but I don't know what could you post.

Comment: Since this is a new project there is no more code. I'm really confused.. Maybe it's the image? its a .png file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my comment i've added a few possible soultions. It is very strange the image isn't showing already. Does it show in the imageview in the xml gui design view?

Anyway here are two possible solutions:
xml:

```
<ImageView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/myimage" />
```

Also your imageview hasn't been assigned an Id which seems weird something like this would be needed for my second idea:

```
<ImageView
               android:id="@+id/Image_ID"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
```

Java side:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //what ever the name of the activity you are using 

        Image=     (ImageView)findViewById(Image_ID);
        Image.setImageResource(Image_ID);
}
```

Lets hope this helps!

**EDIT**

```
<ImageView
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/myimage" />
```

Note fitXY may lower the quality of the image. try messing with the other scale types

Comment: OK, I tried to change the Image and it works. Now the question is what's the problem with the image?

Comment: can you give details of the image? I can only presume off the top of my head the image is to big?

If the image is to large to show you can either make the image smaller using a program like paint.net. or  by checking out my edit

Answer (score 2):

Does your class extend Activity? Try extending AppCompatActivity. I had the same issue and this solution fixed it.

Comment: This solution saved me.